# Jest Error: 'jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have already installed Jest in my React project. I even installed jest-cli, but still can't use Jest in the command line. I can do an npm test, as it is in my package.json, but I have problems with the test, and in order to fix it I need to access the 'jest' command. (I need to run `jest --init` and to create the config file.) Thank you in advance!

See [Getting Started - Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try installing jest as a dev dependency.
`npm install --save-dev jest`

Then run it with `npm test`, (Edit the `package.json` file if necessary to add the script). Don't use `jest` command directly. It's not recommended.
If you want to use `jest` command use `node_modules/.bin/jest`.

Comment: This is how I installed it. I wanted to use a jest command, because I was looking at the official website and its instructions on setting it up (jest --init). It still doesn't run when I put node_modules/.bin/jest in. It says 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: If you are using windows it is `node_modules\.bin\jest.exe` or something like that.

Comment: jest should be in `/node/modules/.bin` if not try to re-install again using this answer post, running again this command solved my problem.

Answer (score 44):

I fixed this problem only after installing jest globally:

```
npm install -g jest
```

Comment: Still works today

Answer (score 9):

You can use `"node_modules\.bin\jest" --init` if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

the problem got fixed when I installed it globally as an Admin (right-click CMD and run as admin) with the below command

```
npm install -g jest
```

then go to the test file and do a jest on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use npx to solve the error "jest: command not found", e.g. npx jest or install the package globally by running npm install -g jest to be able to use the command without the npx prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for my nodejs project. I digged around, and found that my yarn.lock and package-lock.json are not in sync. I might have mistakenly used npm for adding package while i was using yarn for everything else. So when i started work on a new system , jest package was missing in devDependencies. I ran yarn,but of course jest was not installed.
Before someone start pointing we should have only one lock file, i am already aware of it, it was just petty mistake.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).